# Функция для кнопок

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать функцию, для одной кнопки, что бы при нажатие на нее, нажимались все, кнопок более 15, с разными id.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно выбрать группу кнопок и у каждой вызвать метод `click()`

```js
const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group');
for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  groups[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  });
}

document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('All click');
  const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group');
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    groups[i].click();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="all">All</button><br/>
<button class="group">1</button>
<button class="group">2</button>
<button class="group">3</button>
<button class="group">4</button>
<button class="group">5</button>
<button class="group">6</button>
```

Comment: Важный нюанс - Кнопка по которой вызывается метод не должна иметь класс группы, иначе скрипт уйдет в рекурсию.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше это классами делать, а не через ID. Назначить на кнопки, которые надо вызывать, общий класс и искать их через `document.querySelectorAll('.className')`

```js
let buttons = ['#btn1', '#btn2', "#btn3"];
let startBtn = document.querySelector("#start");

//назначаем событие кнопкам.
buttons.forEach((item)=>{
 document.querySelector(item).onclick = () => {
  console.log("Click "+ item)
 }
})

//Назначаем событие на кнопку "start all"
startBtn.onclick = () => {
  console.log("START ALL");
  buttons.forEach(item=>document.querySelector(item).onclick());
 }
```

```html
<button id="btn1">btn</button>
<button id="btn2">btn</button>
<button id="btn3">btn</button>
<button id="start">start all</button>
```